# iOS app status bar is not updating when coming from background to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

I'm working on a cordova ios app, i'm facing this weird behaviour with **status bar**

"when ever i push my app to background and turn of the wifi or put the mobile in airplane mode or enable bluetooth, all these action status getting reflected on the Status bar, but when i open my app from the background state to foreground state, my app status bar always shows the previous state.
I cannot see any changes on the status bar related to Wifi turn on or off, Airplane mode on or off, nothing is getting reflected on my app status bar.

But when i checked it other apps, all the changes are getting reflected on the status bar of the apps at that instant.

Also one other thing, when i keep my app on foreground and changing the wifi or airplane mode using **ControlCenter** status bar getting updated that instant.

Can anyone help me out, What happens to my app status bar when it comes from background to foreground.

Comment: Not sure if tagging this question with `objective-c` is correct here, as you mention working on a `cordova` app. Might be best to tag it with `cordova`?

Comment: @Jasper We are developing the cordova plugin api's in native objective c code. Anyways will tag it out to Cordova. Thank you